# load file content into structure

Tags: c, struct

I wanna load a list of proxies, split each line by the ':' delimiter, then load it into a structure:

```
struct proxy_data {
    ushort type; 
    char *ip;
    uint16_t port;
};


void load_proxies( char * proxy_file )
{
    FILE * in;
    struct proxy_data * temp = NULL;
    if( ( in = fopen( proxy_file, "rt") ) == NULL )
    {
         fprintf( stderr, "\nCan't open input file!\n");
         exit( 0 );
    }
    while( !feof( in ) )
    {
         temp = malloc( sizeof( struct proxy_data ) );
         fscanf(in, "%s ",temp->type);
         fscanf(in, "%s ",temp->ip);
         fscanf(in, "%s ",temp->port);
    };
    fclose( in );
}
```

But I get many errors when compiling.

*How can I load each line into the structure ?*

Comment: What Errors do you get?

Comment: Your `struct` is referencing memory allocated elsewhere (`proxy_data.ip`), therefore writing this `struct` in one instance of the program and reading it in another will result in an invalid reference to unallocated memory and will just plain crash.  You need to marshal your data to write out the contents of the pointer, and think of a way of determining the length of that data.  You cannot do it the way you are attempting to.

Comment: @alk Where does it come from?  It's the `ip` member of `struct proxy_data`.

Comment: the list I have is in the following format TYPE:IP:PORT And I wanna add each element into a structure. If the way I'm trying to achieve this is wrong, can you tell me please how shall I do it? I'm kinda n00b in native c.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
struct proxy_data {
unsigned short type; 
char *ip;
unsigned short port;
};
```

there is no ushort or uint16 in c.

or add

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

in the start of your program

also don't forget to use `ip` wizely so you won't get invalid reference to unallocated memory by allocating the ip before puting values in it. read [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/memory_debugging_parallel_inspector.html)

Comment: he talked about comiler errors, i'll add it @trojanfoe to the answer

Comment: Yes he is talking about compiler errors.  Once those are solved he'll be asking "why does my program crash"?

Comment: @trojanfoe probably, because as I already said I'm a n00b but at least I'm trying to learn by asking the experts so if you wanna be ironic go ahead.

Comment: @ShaMora i'm sorry, i wasn't ironic... or did u ment trojanfoe?
anyway, appologies if i offended you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just write `struct`s to file and expect them to work on anything other than the simplest of cases.  They are platform-specific (think integer sizing and endian issues) and if they contain pointers to other parts of memory, those members will become orphaned when they are read in, resulting in crashes.

The issue you are trying to solve is called [marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) and is basically how internal data structures can be serialised to, and de-serialised from, external data structures (i.e. file or network).

If you are using C++ or Java (you are not, it appears) then consider using solutions like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), which eases this process.

If you have to write your own solution, then you need functions to convert from, say, a string into a instance of `struct`, for example:

```
int decode_proxy_data(const char *string, proxy_data *data) {
    unsigned type, port;
    char ip[32];
    if (sscanf(string, "%u %s %u", &type, ip, &port) == 3) {
        data->type = (ushort)type;
        data->ip = strdup(ip);     // This must be free()'d during destruction!
        data->port = (uint16_t)port;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int encode_proxy_data(char *string, const proxy_data *data) {
    sprintf(string, "%u %s %u", (unsigned)data->type, data->ip, (unsigned)data->port;
    return TRUE;
}
```

You can then read/write strings to the file and this code will work on pretty much any platform (though it's untested, of course).

Please note that memory management is required for `proxy_data.ip` (i.e you must call `free()` on it to avoid memory leaks), but this is the case anyway, regardless of your marshalling issues.

If you have a choice, switch to C++.

Comment: why does it have to be so complicated? I just wanna create a function which loads a list of proxies and checks if they are good or bad.

Comment: @ShaMora Coding *is* complicated.  Otherwise anyone could do it, and we wouldn't be able to earn so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your proxy_dile has the right structure (e.g. als values are stored in textual form), then your `fscanf()`s are wrong. For `port` and `type` it should be

```
fscanf( in, "%hu ", &temp->... );
```

As you want to scan a short integer, for `ip` you have to allocate memory before calling `fscanf()`. Besides you should never use `feof()` together with`fcanf()`. Search SO, you will find a lot of information about that.